# React watch imported class property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm importing a plain class to my react (functional) component and want to be notified when an imported class property is set/updated. I've tried setting my imported class with just `new`, as a state variable with `useState`, as a ref with `useRef` - and have tried passing each one as a parameter to `useEffect`, but none of them are triggering the `useEffect` function when the property is updated a second time.

I've excluded all other code to drill down to the problem. I'm using Typescript, so my plain vanilla `MyClass` looks like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  userId: string
  user: User?
  constructor(userId: string){
    this.userId = userId
    // Do a network call to get the user
    getUser().then(networkUser => {
      // This works because I tried a callback here and can console.log the user
      this.user = networkUser
    }).catch(() => {})
  }
}
```

And then in my component:

```js
// React component
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import MyClass from './MyClass'
export default () => {
  const myClass = new MyClass(userId)

  console.log(myClass.user) // undefined here
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myClass.user) // undefined here and never called again after myClass.user is updated
  }, [myClass.user])

  return null
}
```

Again, this is greatly simplified. But the problem is that React is not re-rendering my component  when the instance user object is updated from `undefined` to a `User`. This is all client side. How do I watch `myClass.user` in a way to trigger a re-render when it finally updates?

Comment: Can you just use `this.render()` to re-render when user is updated?   I dunno, you should add TypeScript tag to this question.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me guess you want to handle the business logic side of the app with OOP then relay the state back to functional React component to display.

You need a mechanism to notify React about the change. And the only way for React to be aware of a (view) state change is via a call to `setState()` somewhere.

The myth goes that React can react to `props` change, `context` change, `state` change. Fact is, `props` and `context` changes are just `state` change at a higher level.

Without further ado, I propose this solution, define a `useWatch` custom hook:

```js
function useWatch(target, keys) {
  const [__, updateChangeId] = useState(0)

  // useMemo to prevent unnecessary calls
  return useMemo(
    () => {
      const descriptor = keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
        const internalKey = `@@__${key}__`

        acc[key] = {
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true,
          get() {
            return target[internalKey]
          },
          set(value) {
            if (target[internalKey] !== value) {
              target[internalKey] = value
              updateChangeId(id => id + 1)  // <-- notify React about the change, 
                                            // the value's not important 
            }
          }
        }
        return acc
      }, {})

      return Object.defineProperties(target, descriptor)
    },
    [target, ...keys]
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
// React component
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useWatch } from './customHooks'
import MyClass from './MyClass'
export default () => {
  const myClass = useMemo(() => new MyClass(userId), [userId])

  useWatch(myClass, ['user'])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myClass.user)
  }, [myClass, myClass.user])

  return null
}
```

---

#### Side Note

Not related to the question per se, but there're a few words I want to add about that myth I mentioned. I said:

> `props` and `context` changes are just `state` change at a higher level

Examples:

`props` change:

```
function Mom() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  setTimeout(() => setValue(v => v+1), 1000)
  return <Kid value={value} />
}

function Dad() {
  let value = 0
  setTimeout(() => value++, 1000)
  return <Kid value={value} />
}

function Kid(props) {
  return `value: ${props.value}`
}
```

`context` change:

```
const Context = React.createContext(0)
function Mom() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  setTimeout(() => setValue(v => v+1), 1000)
  return (<Context.Provider value={value}>
    <Kid />
  </Context.Provider>)
}

function Dad() {
  let value = 0
  setTimeout(() => value++, 1000)
  return (<Context.Provider value={value}>
    <Kid />
  </Context.Provider>)
}

function Kid() {
  const value = React.useContext(Context)
  return `value: ${value}`
}
```

In both examples, only `<Mom />` can get `<Kid />` to react to changes.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I wired it up and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this.user` as props and use props,.user in `useEffeect`. You could do that from the place `getUser` called.

A wholesome solution would be using a centralized state solution like redux or context API. Then you need to update `store` in `getUser` function and listen `globalstate.user`.

**Conclusion**

You need to pass this.user to the component one way or another. You need to choose according to the project.

Comment: I'm trying to separate the logic so React focuses on the view logic but business logic is handled elsewhere. Ideally my component would load and show a loading animation, my class would be initialized and get the user, and then the class would update React which could then update the view. I can't bring redux in today because it's a large existing project and I can't refactor that high up today.

Comment: You might want to check rxjs then. I need to say that you want to achieve is the opposite of doing the React way in my humble opinion. And here is an example if rxjs-react; https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/13/react-rxjs-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: The thing is not about prop. React only trigger a re-render when some sorta setState is called

Comment: @ilkerkaran check the side note part of my answer.

Comment: Also check [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/172b2334d3a1240248c049a40b88a845bd0ecf5d/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L116) in source code of `react-redux` lib. The trick is to call `forceComponentUpdateDispatch()` to notify React about store state change. That call traced back to `useReducer()` which is just another form of `setState()`. All I'm saying is simply "pass as props" or "use contextAPI" alone doesn't solve OP's problem.